# aka 'NSString' has no member - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a QR code reader using Swift 4 and have been running into some problems, particular these messages on multiple lines:

> Type 'AVMediaType' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'video'
>
> Type 'AVMetadataObject.ObjectType' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'qr'
>
> Type 'AVLayerVideoGravity' (aka 'NSString') has no member has no member 'resizeAspectFill'

But, [the sample project I've been following](https://www.appcoda.com/barcode-reader-swift/) builds perfectly with the same code I have.

Here's an example of the first part of my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class ScanViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession?.self
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Get the back-facing camera for capturing videos
        //***ERROR OCCURRS ON THIS LINE***
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInDualCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back)
        
        guard let captureDevice = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first else {
            print("Failed to get the camera device")
            return
        }
```

Does anyone know what's causing it and how to fix it?

Comment: remove `@available(iOS 10.0, *)` from your code and change your deployment target in IB and for your capture device 
 `AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)`

Comment: @LeoDabus are you recommending replacing the entire line starting with "let deviceDiscoverySession" with that?

Comment: yes just get the default camera. I would choose a better naming also `do {
            guard
                let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
                case let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            else { return }  // code ... } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }`

Comment: Looks good, but can you clarify what you mean by "change your deployment target in IB"? leave a full answer so i can mark it correct!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7y4h3qjatledh1/Screen%20Shot%202018-01-28%20at%208.36.35%20PM.png?dl=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

The solution is instead of `video` being a property of `AVMediaType`, `AVMediaTypeVideo` is its own thing. Use that for Swift 4 in iOS 10.2 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment target looks like `iOS 10.0`. `AVMediaType` and `AVLayerVideoGravity` are available from `iOS 11`. You should either increase your Deployment Target or use older alternatives like `AVMediaTypeVideo`

Answer (score 0):

Fix as follows for Swift 4.x

Change

```
AVMediaType.video
```

to

```
AVMediaTypeVideo
```